# Google's Inspect URL shows incorrect source code for my page's "Google Index", but correct for "Live Test"

Tags: google-search-console, google-search, googlebot

My web page is incorrectly indexed and is showing a different header than the one that is actually updated in my website.

When I used the URL Inspection Tool in Google Search Console, The index shows the wrong information as shown below:

[image: URL Inspect Incorrect Information on Google Index]

When I use the "URL Inspect" to check for "Live Version" it returns the correct information as shown below:

[image: URL Inspect - Correct Information on Live Test]

From my understanding, the results should be same, assuming a delay in the indexing but the results remain different from a long time. As a result, when I do search in Google for my indexed page, it shows the incorrect information as shown below:

[image: Displayed SERP Inccorect Information on Google]

How can I fix this and show the correctly information on the indexed page?

Comment: Where did Google get the idea that your site was for a Thai restaurant?   Is that an old version of the page?    If not, there is a real possibility that your site is hacked.

Comment: There is a connection to Thai restaurant. We have the single web site for many customers (http://mike.schwede.ch, http://le-basilic.ch, etc). So, they are in the same database, but our code behaves the way, that they are independent, because the sites belong to the different customers. So, it's not hacked.

Comment: So at some point your server may have served the Thai restaurant page for your personal site?   If that is the case, Google will update eventually.  It may just take several weeks.   When you say "long time", how long are you talking about?

Comment: Yes, our web site has many sub domains and it serves all the customers this way. Regarding 301 and canonical links we didn't change anything for several months.

Answer (score 2):

Use "Fetch as Google" option in the Search Console and Request for Indexing. This is one way of you getting the correct headers to be displayed in web results:

`https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/googlebot-fetch?hl=en&authuser=2&siteUrl=https://www.example.com`

> When you submit the request, it will appear like below:
>
> You can click on Request Indexing to submit a request to google for the changes.

[image: Fetch As google]

> Additionally, you can check what Google has fetched by clicking the arrow mark and observing the title and meta as highlighted below:

[image: http fetch response from google]

> Once you have completed this, allow for some time to see your search results again. (For my website, when I do any changes and request for indexing, I observe it updated in less than 30 minutes but this totally depends on how Google crawls the website.)

Comment: I've already pressed this 'Fetch button' and clicked the arrow mark to see the details and it shows the correct version (https://www.dropbox.com/s/hw7geacd2tgli78/fetch%20as%20google.png?dl=0). Yes, I clicked 'Request Indexing' button.

Comment: Give some more time to Google. Also I tried to access your site, it redirects me from / to /home/de/live. When I did a site search, the redirected URL shows the correct response. Is this your index page? http://prntscr.com/mkww74

Comment: Also, your code is not pretty good as you are trying to get all the things you want to display in the "head" section. This is just a personal opinion. If it is not your index page, you should your index page.

Comment: okay, we will wait more time, though our web site was not updated the whole month, so it should be already indexed in the correct way. /home/de/live is our index (home/landing) page. In the head section we set title and description, but it's correct I think.

Comment: Yes your title and meta are correct. Was commenting on the content, since it is a good practice to have content in the body section instead.

Comment: I just noticed that your / sends a HTTP 200 OK response but no 301 response to your /home/de/live. This might be a problem. This is your flow: / to /home/init to /home/de/live. Can you check this?

Comment: If you check view-source:https://mike.schwede.ch/ you see that we use canonical url that is set to 'https://mike.schwede.ch/home/de/live'. That's why we don't need 301 to /home/de/live, but maybe I am wrong. As for canonical url is the same as 301 in that sense.

Comment: Yes, better is to have content inside, but we use angular, that's why data is not inside after server rendering.

Comment: Canonical URL is not same as 301. Canonical tells the Search Engine to consider the relevant URL to show in SERP. But it is upto the Search Engines to honor this request to show the results. A 301 forces SERP to show the resulting URL and ensures that the link juice is transferred to the new URL being redirected to.

Comment: The above should fix your issue. Once you confirm its solved, I will add it as another answer to help community find the right fix for these kind of problems.

Comment: What's wrong with this https://mike.schwede.ch/home/de/live/geldmacherei02eb141e15bc link then? Here is no canonical link, no 301, but still SERP shows incorrect info. Again Google Index and Live Test show different result (Google Index shows again the wrong version, while Live Test is okay).

Comment: The same problem. Google is showing data for that URL. You can check here: http://www.redirect-checker.org/index.php

Unless you do your redirection correctly, nobody can help. At this point, it is an assumption that the indexing is not proper because of your old URLs cache being displayed and no proper redirection being done.