# Why does Google show foreign language text my website does not contain?

Tags: google-search, search-engine-indexing

If I Google ["Energy Council"](https://www.google.com/search?q=energy%20concil&source=hp&ei=hyxRY6vdKInN2roPrcKV-A0&iflsig=AJiK0e8AAAAAY1E6lykmNY0zq5hY47Q4D2jpCq_elY56&ved=0ahUKEwjrvOTt1e76AhWJplYBHS1hBd8Q4dUDCAo&uact=5&oq=energy%20concil&gs_lcp=Cgdnd3Mtd2l6EAMyDQguEIAEEMcBEK8BEA0yBwgAEIAEEA0yBwgAEIAEEA0yBwgAEIAEEA0yBwgAEIAEEA0yBwgAEIAEEA0yDQguEIAEEMcBEK8BEA0yBwgAEIAEEA0yBwgAEIAEEA0yBwgAEIAEEA06CwguEIAEELEDEIMBOhEILhCABBCxAxCDARDHARDRAzoFCAAQgAQ6CwguEIAEEMcBENEDOgsIABCABBCxAxCDAToRCC4QgAQQsQMQgwEQxwEQrwE6CwgAEIAEELEDEMkDOggIABCABBCxAzoICAAQsQMQgwE6CwguEIAEEMcBEK8BOgcIABCABBAKUABY6g5g7BBoAHAAeACAAc0BiAGjEZIBBjAuMTEuMpgBAKABAQ&sclient=gws-wiz) Google shows me search results like this:

*Le Restaurant
Restaurant à Sainte-savine/ Troyes proposant des plats simples 'fait-maison' avec des produits de qualité. Restauration traditionnelle française ...*

Note the French text - none of which appears on the site or in the source or via the developer tools *Inspect elements*.

Even when I create new pages with no content Google Search Content shows them to be for this French restaurant, see this [video as an example](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SPItOIeOcNA&t=17s) which goes through this process.

I cannot work out why this is so, any help is much appreciated.

Comment: This post may help, seems to be the same problem as you are having - https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/120981/googles-inspect-url-shows-incorrect-source-code-for-my-pages-google-index-b - and it also shows the benefit of posting a question with all the materials in it. If that does not help please update your question such that I would be of benefit to others with the same problem in the future.

Comment: The above is slightly different but thanks for the comment. Will repost a more useful question.

Comment: Did you try the fetch? It should land you right back into your console search after fetching ... https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/googlebot-fetch?hl=en&authuser=2&siteUrl=https://www.energycouncil.com.au/ I used the translate tool and it worked so the problem is not google is going to the wrong place. Obviously I can not use the fetch because your site is not part of my search console. I would guess the view as is where the problem exists, so you need to fetch.

Comment: By 'Fetch' do you mean 'Test Live Url' on 'Url Inspection' in Google Search Console?

Comment: Also I have reposted a better question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74146618/why-does-test-live-url-in-google-search-console-return-content-that-is-not-viewa

Comment: @Wayne I am here if you would like to screen share https://meet.jit.si/UsualCoordinatorsSurrenderArticulately

Comment: I worked it out!

Code had been injected into a source code file that redirects the site if it is a website indexer. Ingeniously, this code did not do anything for over a year so I didn't see the issue as no files appeared to be recently modified.

To find the issue, download the live site and search it for "redirect"